# Show fields in infowindow from my custom layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, mobile, popup, fields-attributes

I want to display two fields from the POIData layer. What I get now is `${ToegangsNr} ${Baanvak}` in text. Does anyone know how to do this in an DynamicMapServiceLayer?

```
POIData = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("https://gis.strukton.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/POI_Data/MapServer", { id: "POI", "visible":false });
map.addLayer(POIData);
dojo.connect(map, "onClick", function(evt) {
    map.infoWindow.resize(175, 125);
    var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setStyle(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_X).setSize(12);
    symbol.outline.setWidth(4).setColor("blue");
    dojo.connect(map, "onClick", function(evt) {
        map.graphics.clear();
        var graphic = new esri.Graphic(evt.mapPoint, symbol);
        map.graphics.add(graphic);
        map.infoWindow.setTitle("<b>${ToegangsNr}</b>");
        map.infoWindow.setContent("<tr>Baanvak: <td>${Baanvak}</tr></td>");
        map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
    });
    dojo.connect(map.infoWindow, "onHide", function() {
        map.graphics.clear();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the substituted data, you'll need to set the graphic's InfoTemplate, instead of setting the InfoWindow directly. Here's an example using your code.

```
var POITemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate();
POITemplate.setTitle("<b>${ToegangsNr}</b>");
POITemplate.setContent("<tr>Baanvak: <td>${Baanvak}</tr></td>");

// a little further down in your code.

dojo.connect(map, "onClick", function(evt) {
    map.graphics.clear();
    var graphic = new esri.Graphic(evt.mapPoint, symbol);

    graphic.setInfoTemplate(POITemplate);

    map.graphics.add(graphic);

    map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint, map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
});
```